# How do I use javascript or jquery to climb the DOM looking only at direct parents, but not uncles/aunts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, parent

I have a need to climb up the DOM tree to the parent, grandparent, great grandparent of a node, etc (without any of their siblings) and to set some properties. I thought that a simple recursion running up the tree would do the trick, but I just can't get it to work. I've tried lots of different things that seem logical, but javascript is not cooperating with me. Can anyone help?

Here's a JSFiddle showing a non-working version of what I'm trying to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/ry8ojoaj/

```
// This function should climb up the chain of parent 'group's (but not uncles or aunts)
// and set their 'group-things' to have a red background
var setParentChainText = function(node) {
    if (!node) { return; }

    node.css('background-color', 'red');

    var parent = node.closest('.group').first()

    if (node.hasClass('group-thing')) {
        parent = node.parents('.group').first()
    }
    var parentThing = parent.find('.group-thing').first();
    setParentChainText(parentThing);
}

$(function() {
    var theOne = $('.the-one');

    var parent = theOne.closest('.group');
    var parentThing = parent.find('.group-thing').first();

    var grandparent = parent.parents('.group').first();
    var grandparentThing = grandparent.find('.group-thing').first();

    // uncommenting these will color the "top thing" and "parent thing" red.
    //parentThing.css('background-color','red');
    //grandparentThing.css('background-color','red');

    // This call alone should color the "top thing" and "parent thing" red, but it doesn't.
    setParentChainText(theOne);
});
```

and the HTML for the example:

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="group-thing">top thing</div>

    <div class="group">
        <div class="group-thing">uncle thing</div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="child-thing">item</div>
            <div class="child-other">other</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="child-thing">item</div>
            <div class="child-other">other</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="child-thing">item</div>
            <div class="child-other">other</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="group-thing">parent thing</div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="child-thing the-one">The One</div>
            <div class="child-other">other</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="child-thing">item</div>
            <div class="child-other">other</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="child-thing">item</div>
            <div class="child-other">other</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="group-thing">uncle thing</div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="child-thing">item</div>
            <div class="child-other">other</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="child-thing">item</div>
            <div class="child-other">other</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="child-thing">item</div>
            <div class="child-other">other</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems that your data is not a tree but a networks. Code to handle trees and that to handle networks are different in general. Are you sure that your data is tree?

Comment: I'm not sure, perhaps we have different terminology. The 'body' node of the DOM is what I think of as a 'root' node of a tree. Every node has a parent and children, just like a tree. I'm not familiar with networks or how they're different data structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code was what was getting you stuck:

```
if (node.hasClass('group-thing')) {
parent = node.parents('.group').first()
}
```

That just finds the same "group" parent again and stays within the first group over and over again.

Change to: 
    var parent = node.hasClass('group-thing') ? node.parent().parent() : node.closest('.group');

Here is my fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/nhmaggiej/wtdsa5cq/

Answer (score 0):

As far as moving up the parent chain you can do something like the following example with plain JavaScript. It's just a simple while loop but the same idea can be applied with a recursive function.

JSBin example: http://jsbin.com/jerisisagi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```
var node = document.getElementById('start');

// Make sure to stop at the body
while (node && node.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'body') {
  node.className = 'box';
  node = node.parentNode; // move to next parent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is there working code of your program using `jquery`...

```js
$(function() {
    $('.the-one').addClass('colorbackground').closest('.group').find('.group-thing').addClass('colorbackground');
});
```

```css
.group {
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.item {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.colorbackground{
    background-color : red;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group">
 <div class="group-thing">top thing</div>

 <div class="group">
  <div class="group-thing">uncle thing</div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="child-thing">item</div>
   <div class="child-other">other</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="child-thing">item</div>
   <div class="child-other">other</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="child-thing">item</div>
   <div class="child-other">other</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="group">
  <div class="group-thing">parent thing</div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="child-thing the-one">The One</div>
   <div class="child-other">other</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="child-thing">item</div>
   <div class="child-other">other</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="child-thing">item</div>
   <div class="child-other">other</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="group">
  <div class="group-thing">uncle thing</div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="child-thing">item</div>
   <div class="child-other">other</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="child-thing">item</div>
   <div class="child-other">other</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="child-thing">item</div>
   <div class="child-other">other</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't color the grandparents of 'The One' node, it only colors the parent. I need to 'climb the DOM looking at direct parents' all the way to the great-great-great.... grandparents and the root node.